# Multivariate Random Number Generation in Matlab

Tags: matlab, random, covariance

I'm probably being a little dense but I'm not very mathsy and can't seem to understand the covariance element of creating multivariate data.

I'm after two columns of random data (representing two correlated variables).

I think I am right in needing to use the mvnrnd function and I understand that 'mu' must be a column of my mean vectors. As I need 4 distinct classes within my data these are going to be (1, 1) (-1 1) (1 -1) and (-1 -1). I assume I will have to do the function 4x with a different column of mean vectors each time and then combine them to get my full data set.

I don't understand what I should put for SIGMA - Matlab help tells me that it must be 'a d-by-d symmetric positive semi-definite matrix, or a d-by-d-by-n array' i.e. a covariance matrix. I don't understand how I create a covariance matrix for numbers that I am yet to generate.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The [_covariance matrix_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-covariance_matrix#Statistics) is something that defines and determines the distribution, that's why it's part of the input, just like _mean_ and _standard deviation_.

Comment: sorry, it's probably my prof-bias, but what about accompanying with an example and some crude numbers what you aim for?

Comment: 4 Gaussian distributions in 2 dimensional feature space (1000 cases in total). The prior probability for each distribution should be 0.25 and the mean vectors must be class1 = (1,1), c2 = (1,-1), c3 = (-1,1) and c4 = (-1,-1). It is just simulated data to play around with for remote sensing classification purposes. I'm currently altering the Matlab example to  understand what changing the values in the covariance matrix actually does. Thanks for your link :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that I understood your case properly, I would go this way:

```
data = [normrnd(0,1,5000,1),normrnd(0,1,5000,1)]; %% your starting data series
MU = mean(data,1);
SIGMA = cov(data);
```

Now, it should be possible to feed `mvnrnd` with `MU` and `SIGMA`:

```
r = mvnrnd(MU,SIGMA,5000);
plot(r(:,1),r(:,2),'+') %% in case you wanna plot the results
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: be aware that mine was only a pretty rough example. I don't know if your data underline any expected covariance matrix.

Answer (score 0):

I think your aim is to generate the simulated multivariate gaussian distributed data. For example, I use

`k = 6; % feature dimension 
mu = rand(1,k); 
sigma = 10*eye(k,k);`

unit matrix by 10 times is a symmetric positive semi-definite matrix. And the gaussian distribution will be more round than other type of sigma.

then you can use it as the above example of mvnrnd function and see the plot.